# Auto-hibernate with udev rule

Tags: systemd, udev, power-management, hibernate

I'm using Debian Jessie with systemd. In the past I've used an acpid script that let's my computer hibernate when the battery is 5% or below.

In an attempt to make a replacement for that I've made this udev rule (as the described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/laptop#suspend_on_low_battery_level) in the Arch wiki):

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-lowbat.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{status}=="Discharging", ATTR{capacity}=="5", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl hibernate" 
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{status}=="Discharging", ATTR{capacity}=="4", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl hibernate"
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{status}=="Discharging", ATTR{capacity}=="3", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl hibernate"
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{status}=="Discharging", ATTR{capacity}=="2", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl hibernate"
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{status}=="Discharging", ATTR{capacity}=="1", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl hibernate"
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{status}=="Discharging", ATTR{capacity}=="0", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl hibernate"
```

It's not working.

I've tried making this test rule which works:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/98-discharging.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{status}=="Discharging", RUN+="/usr/bin/touch /home/myname/discharging"
```

Why doesn't the first rule work to hibernate my laptop?

Comment: `udevadm monitor` should let you know if the battery sends events when the charge level changes. `udevadm info -q property -a --path /sys/class/power_supply/BAT_0` (or whatever the actual path to the battery is) will let you know if udev has a capacity attribute for it. Those may need to be run as root (or via sudo).

Comment: That gives me `ATTR{capacity}=="79"` which is the same as I get from `acpi` so I guess that works ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path you used for systemctl is wrong. systemctl is in /bin/, not /usr/bin/ (this is Debian/Ubuntu specific).